# Spherical basis representation of a dyad

Tags: quantum-mechanics, tensor-calculus, representation-theory

Consider a dyad $C$ formed from two real vectors $a$ and $b$ such that its Cartesian components are
$$
C_{\mu\nu} = a_\mu b_\nu \qquad
$$
with $a_\mu$ and $b_\nu$ being the Cartesian components of $a$ and $b$, e.g., $C_{xy} = a_x b_y$. I want to change to the spherical basis with unit vectors
$$
\hat e_+ = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \hat e_x - \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\hat e_y
$$
$$
\hat e_- = +\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \hat e_x - \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\hat e_y
$$
$$
\hat e_0 = \hat e_z
$$
I know that the representation of $\bar a$ and $\bar b$ in this basis are, e.g.,
$$
\begin{align}
a 
&= (a\cdot\hat e_+^*) \hat e_+
+ (a\cdot\hat e_-^*) \hat e_-
+ (a\cdot\hat e_0^*) \hat e_0  \\
&= \left(-\frac{a_x}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{i a_y}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \hat e_+
+ \left(\frac{a_x}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{i a_y}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \hat e_-
+ a_z \hat e_0 \\
&= \sum_p a_p \hat e_p
\end{align}
$$
So my instinct is to form the representation of $C$ by juxtaposing the spherical basis representations of $a$ and $b$:
$$
C \stackrel{?}{=} \sum_{p,q} a_p b_q \hat e_p \hat e_q
$$
and then I would read off its matrix elements as
$$
C_{pq} = \hat e_p^* \cdot C \cdot \hat e_q^* = a_p b_q
$$
Is this the correct way to obtain the spherical basis representation of a dyad, or have I made some mistake with respect to complex conjugation? Or perhaps some deeper group-theoretical consideration?

Comment: Looks OK; what would your qualms be? Try a simple particular example.

Comment: The reason we use $\hat e^{\pm}$ and $\hat e^0$ is because they are eigenvectors of a rotation through $\phi$ about the z-axis with eigenvalue $e^{\pm i\phi}$ and $1$, respectively. Their dyadic products aren't necessarily Eigen-dyads, so are you sure this what you want? (Note that $\hat e^+\hat e^+$ _is_ an eigendyad with eigenvalue $e^{2 i\phi}$, so there are some useful combinations).